# Cannot see dropdown Unit Tests in IntelliJ IDEA running a Corda training program

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, corda

I am just starting to learn Corda and have loaded up the training program using Gradle. I  am using Windows 10 and running Intellij IDEA 2018.3. The problem is that I am following the training videos from R3/Corda and I cannot find the Unit Test option in Intellij. Anyone know what I am doing wrong? I tried to set it up manually but could not figure it out. Thanks!

[image: corda]

Updates:

Now based on the answer given, I checked if Junit was enabled and it is. I get the following errors when I try and add a configuration and select a class:

[image]
[image]

@CrazyCoder So here are the results of my next attempt. When I follow the suggestions I had the following results:

[image]

I clicked the green arrow next to the unit test to run it. It seems to run but complains that the name is too long. I figured it out by changing the configuration **Shorten command line** to **JAR manifest** as below and it worked!

[image]
I also figured out that in order to get rid of the errors regarding Amount and Currency that I needed to include:

```
import net.corda.core.contracts.Amount
import net.corda.core.contracts.ContractState
```

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have JUnit plug-in disabled in IntelliJ IDEA settings. Try to [enable it back](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/enabling-and-disabling-plugins.html). Use JUnit Run/Debug configuration type, not Android JUnit.

See also [Editing Run/Debug Configurations](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-editing-run-debug-configurations.html).

With JUnit plug-in enabled it should look like this:

[image: JUnit Run/Debug configuration]

Run/Debug configuration can be **created automatically by clicking on the arrow** on the left of the test method in the code:

[image: Run]

It will specify the class and the module classpath automatically. See the screenshot above with the correct settings for the `hasIOUAmountFieldOfCorrectType` method. Notice that **Class** is set to `net.corda.training.state.IOUStateTests`, **Use classpath of module** is set to `com.template.kotlin-source.test` which is different from the module shown on your screenshot.

Yet another way to run the test for the method is via the right click context menu, it works the same as clicking on the arrow. There is also an option to create the Run configuration without running it:

[image: Run/Create]

You can find the complete guide for running Unit tests in IntelliJ IDEA in the official documentation: [Creating Run/Debug Configuration for Tests](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-run-debug-configuration-for-tests.html).

JUnit dependency is added automatically to the module when the project is imported correctly from Gradle (you should see them in the Project View | External Libraries and in the [Module Dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GfdqY.png)). If you don't have JUnit library there, try to [Refresh/Reimport](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yr5A6.png) the Gradle project and ensure there are no errors when importing.

*JUnit not found in module...* error is most likely displayed because you have the wrong module specified in **Use classpath of module**.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me so quickly. I have edited the question to include additional steps I have tried, but I still can't get it to work! Any ideas?

Comment: @PhilipRutovitz I've updated the answer, see also https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-run-debug-configuration-for-tests.html.